# Set product price in WooCommerce by quantity and weight

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I don't find how to customize my pricing in my WordPress WebShop with the WooCommerce plugin.

I would like to have:

- Article A   12€/kg
- Article B    3€/piece
- Article C   12€/colli

How is this possible please?

greets
Wim

Answer (score 1):

You can add this on your functions.php

```
// Filter on cart price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_price' ,  'custom_price', 10, 2);
// Filter on product page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html' ,      'custom_price', 10, 2);

function custom_price( $price, WC_Product $product ){

    // You can store the unit as custom fields
    $unit = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'unit', true );

    // Then concatenate with the price
    $price .=  $unit;

    return $price;
}
```

Then you have to add a custom field on each product :
[image: Custom Fields]